# Setting Geometry Fail Error on ESRI server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I'm trying to insert a point on a feature layer on a ESRI server.
Sometimes it works nicely, but sometimes I get an error when I send the save instruction:
"Setting of Geometry Fail"

This happens when I build the geometry from a mappoint. When I compare the geometry from a mappoint with a normal geometry, I don't find any difference.
The mappoint is made only by using X,Y and WKID.

Can anyone have a clue of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I found the problem. The problem was that I was converting my X,Y from a string to a double and I was loosing the comma in the process. After correcting this, it was ok.